# FreeBSD doesn't preserve POSIX message queue descriptions over forks

Tags: c, linux, message-queue, freebsd

I have a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
  struct mq_attr attrs;
  attrs.mq_maxmsg = 10;
  attrs.mq_msgsize = sizeof(int);

  const char name[] = "/test-queue";

  mqd_t q = mq_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0600, &attrs);
  if (q == (mqd_t)-1) {
    perror("mq_open");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  mq_unlink(name); // it doesn't matter if I do this at the end or not

  if (fork()) {
    int msg = 666;
    if (mq_send(q, (const char *)&msg, sizeof(msg), 1)) {
      perror("mq_send");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  } else {
    int msg;
    unsigned priority;
    if (mq_receive(q, (char *)&msg, sizeof(msg), &priority) == -1) {
      perror("mq_receive");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%d\n", msg);
  }

  mq_close(q);

  return 0;
}
```

I compile this program using `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -o mqtest mqtest.c -lrt` on two platforms:

- Linux kallikanzarid-desktop 3.8.0-31-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:03:44 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- FreeBSD bsd.localhost 9.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE #0 r255898: Thu Sep 26 22:50:31 UTC 2013     root@bake.isc.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

On Linux, everything works. On FreeBSD, I get `mq_receive: Bad file descriptor`. Moving the `mq_unlink` call to the end of `main()` doesn't help. Is there a way to fix this, or do I have to postpone marking the queue for deletion and reopen it after the fork?

Comment: Re: `mq_unlink()`, POSIX specifies: _If one or more processes have the message queue open when  mq_unlink()  is called, destruction of the message queue shall be postponed until all references to the message queue have been closed._ The POSIX standard can be viewed at: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD *does* preserve message queue descriptors. See mq_open(2):

> FreeBSD implements message queue based on file descriptor.  The descriptor is inherited by child after fork(2).  The descriptor is closed in a new image after exec(3).  The select(2) and kevent(2) system calls are supported for message queue descriptor.

**Edit**:

The  structure that `mqd_t` points to *does* contain a descriptor. But if you test that file descriptor just after the `fork()` using `fcntl()`, it also returns EBADF.

This is a bug in FreeBSD. But wether the bug is in the docs or in the implementation I cannot say.

Comment: Did you try it yourself? For me, reopening the message queue in the child was the workaround that helped, so I doubt the idea that the parent unlinking it is the problem.

Comment: POSIX `fork()` specifies: _The child process shall have its own copy of the message queue descriptors of the parent. Each of the message descriptors of  the  child  shall refer to the same open message queue description as the corresponding message descriptor of the parent._